# Spring saml is looping back to Identity Provider

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, saml, spring-saml

I have a spring application that I am trying to set up with single sign on through a third party Identity provider.

I have this working in test, but when I move it over to prod it is looping.

My application sends over the SAMLRequest, then I enter username and password.  IdP sends SAMLResponse over to https://example.com/saml/SSO endpoint.  At this point it should 302 redirect to my sign in controller like it does in test, but it ends up looping back and 302'ing to the IdP.  The IdP sends another new SAMLResponse and /saml/sso loops back endlessly.

Any ideas on why this happens?  Lastly, the IdP side is handled by another department, so i can't check the logs on that side.  My tomcat logs though are free of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, but figure I would share what my issue was.  Long story short, I had two servers in an IIS server farm and it seems that the session was always starting on server 1, but the SAMLReponse would be sent to server 2 and cause it to reject it.  I turned on Affinity Control and all was fixed.